# How do I use a C# string in my .aspx webpage?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have passed a value through a url to a C# .net page using query string.  The url of the page looks like this:

```
http://contoso.com/products.aspx?field1=value1
```

And in C#, I have this to catch it:

```
String myValue = Request.QueryString["field1"];
```

What im looking to do is use this value in the page, something like this:

```
<h1><%# Eval("myValue") %></h1>
```

How would I go about doing this?  Obviously this HTML code doesn't work. I have exhausted some google searches on the subject so any information would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either create a `Property` on your page and use code tags, or set the `h1` tag as `runat="server"` and set the value like that.

Property:

```
public string MyString{ get; set; }

public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyString = Request.QueryString["field1"];
}
```

Then in your markup:

```
<h1><%= MyString %></h1>
```

Alternatively, using the `runat="server"` method on the `h1` tag:

Markup:

```
<h1 id="myH1" runat="server"></h1>
```

Code:

```
myH1.InnerText = Request.QueryString["field1"].ToString();
```

Comment: Using the <h1 id="myH1" runat="server"></h1> method works.  But I cant get the <h1><%= MyString %></h1> to work. :(

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `runat="server"` and `id` to your `h1` tag, so you can use it in cs-file.
HTML:

```
<h1 id="myHeader" runat="server"></h1>
```

CS:

```
myHeader.InnerText = myValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your aspx file, you can define a text field like so:

```
 <h1 Id="label" runat="server"/>
```

Then, in your code behind file add:

```
label.InnerText = Request.QueryString["field1"];
```